# CSS3 animations not working on angular 4

Tags: angular, css, css-animations

why css3 animations not work in angular 4? 
I have to enable some property?
I have tried to import `BrowserAnimationModule` without any result.
I've search a lot but all I have found is to use Angular methods to show animations.

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="score-addition" *ngIf="(game.lastScore | async) > 0">{{'+' + (game.lastScore | async)}}</div>
```

and my CSS class

```
.score-addition {
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
color: red;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgba(119, 110, 101, 0.9);
z-index: 100;
-webkit-animation: move-up 600ms ease-in;
-moz-animation: move-up 600ms ease-in;
animation: move-up 600ms ease-in;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both; }
```

but the animation doesn't work. 
 I have also try this without success:

```
<div class="score-addition" [hidden]="(game.lastScore | async) == 0">{{'+' + (game.lastScore | async)}}</div>
```

Comment: Well first of all, I think the `animation` needs a `keyframes` property. Second, what are you trying to animate ? Do you want to animate the div at start, or do you want it to be animated when it is being hidden ?

Comment: @trichetriche I have used this animation in an angularjs application and it works, I want to animate the div when `game.lastScore > 0`.

Comment: AngularJS isn't Angular. And I'm pretty sur you forgot the `@keyframes move-up` css chunk from your AngularJS application. Also, when you use *ngIf, the div is deleted from the DOM. See it as a `display: none`. Since you can't animate a display property, this might explain your issue. Angular has a whole tutorial about animations, but I could give you an already made-up one if you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment : you can use [Angular 4 built-in animation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) to do what you want. I only give you the code, for CSS, I'll let you chose your properties.

You need to add, in your Component decorator, the `animate` property. (Also, remember to import the keywords from `@angular/animations`)

```
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';
```

Now for your decorator :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'YourSelector',
  templateUrl: 'your HTML template path',
  styleUrls: ['your CSS file path'],
  animations: [
    trigger('moveUp', [
      state('void', style({
        // Add the CSS for the hidden state here. Here is 2 examples (camelCase for properties of more than 1 word)
        height: '0',
        borderBottom: 'none'
      })),
      state('*', style({
        // Here, add the CSS of the visible state. You can use the * wildcard to tell Angular 'calculate the value of the height for me'
        height: '*',
        borderBottom: '*'
      })),
      // animate format: 'DURATION [DELAY] EASING-FUNCTION'
      transition(':enter', animate('275ms ease-out')),
      transition(':leave', animate('275ms 275ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

Now, in your HTML, what you need to do is

```
<div class="score-addition" [@moveUp]="(game.lastScore | async) > 0" *ngIf="(game.lastScore | async) > 0">{{'+' + (game.lastScore | async)}}</div>
```